# Need element to identify where it is on the page when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element that changes color when the user scrolls past a certain section on the web page and it all works fine unless the user has already scrolled passed the section but then refreshes the page.

When the page is refreshed the page remains on its last position but the element color returns to its original CSS color.

e.g.

- first section has a black background - need the element in question to be white
- when scrolled passed first section need the element to then change to gray
- if the user reloads the page (after scrolling past the first section) the element returns to white.  This is not good as all sections after the first section have a background of white so therefore need the element to be gray

in essence, I am looking to see if there is a way that JavaScript/JQuery can identify what section the element is against once the page has refreshed and then add the correct CSS properties accordingly.

here is the code I currently have:

```
var targetOffset = $("#firstSection").offset().top;

  var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($w.scrollTop() >= targetOffset) {
      $(".element").css({ color: "#636C72" });
    } else {
      $(".element").css({ color: "white" });
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger scroll when you define it so the logic runs.

```
var $w = $(window).scroll(function() { }).scroll()
```

or with trigger

```
var $w = $(window).scroll(function() { }).trigger('scroll')
```

or make it a function

```
var scrollFnc = function () {}
var $w = $(window).scroll(scrollFnc)
scrollFnc()
```

Comment: please could you show me how this would look with my code included.  Do I implement after the 'if' statement?

Comment: Thanks just figured it out!  Not entirely sure of the logic behind it though.  if you have time to give me a quick explanation that would be awesome!

Comment: It calls the function and runs it?